# NetSuite: Filter join in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to add a search filter to a search in SuiteScript. What I want to filter is the date a custom record is created. The search is off a job (or Project) record, but the custom record is connected to the job (this needs to be off the job for other reasons).

In the UI this would like like: CustomRecordName : Date Created  (and as a filter you would select the filter you want, such as within this fiscal quarter).

I know the syntax:

```
new nlobjSearchFilter(fieldId, join, operator, value1, value2);
```

I went to the custom record and the "Date Created" fieldId is 'created'. My Custom record's id is: customrecord301.

Here is what I have for my specific case:

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('created', 'customrecord301', 'within', 'thisfiscalquarter'));
```

I get the following error:
An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid join ID, or is not in proper syntax: created.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `join` parameter should be the ID of the *field* you are joining through instead of the record type you are joining to. Instead of "customrecord301", you need the ID of the list/record field on the Project (job) record.

Comment: There isn't a field though... The custom Record links to the Job - field on custom record of type Job and set to Parent. So on the Job, in the UI, there is a list of the Custom Records. 

Best way to explain is like Messages. If someone sends an email from a Job, it is listed under the Messages tab, but there is no actual field for it. However, in a search you can filter by Messages: Subject (for example).

Comment: Ok for anyone who reads this I worked off what @egrubaugh360 said and found the answer. If you are using a sublist, like I was, then you need the sublist id. The way to find this is to hover over the sublist and look at the bottom of your window. It will show javascript:void("sublistId"); . So for Messages, it showed "messages". Using this id, the join worked and all is well with the world!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put any value in 'join' until and unless you are executing a joined search.

Please try this
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('created', null, 'within', 'thisfiscalquarter'));

Comment: I am doing a join. Please see my second comment on the above answer that explains what I did.